# jQuery toggle multiple areas individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to show and hide areas on my site with just a toggle. Which works fine, but if i have multiple elements I want to show and hide individually on the page I have to write a bit of jQuery for each item. Is there a way to do it for a class or ID within the encapsulating class?

heres my jQuery:

```
 jQuery('.collapse').click(function() {


        jQuery('#filterArea').toggle('slow', function() {

        });

    });
```

And heres my content:

```
<div class="tabs"> 
    <div class="ui-widget-header">
        <div class="collapse" id="boxId">Content Box</div>

    </div><br />
        <div class="addPadLeftNoFloat" id="filterArea">

            <p>Content for box</p>

        </div>              
</div>
```

I want to be able to have a few areas on the page with the class of collapse that just close the filterArea within the outer collapse? Or similar? I'm not doing a great job of explaining this! - So if i have two divs with the class of collapse, when i click them the filterarea of that div collapses

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having `filterArea` as an `id`, change it to a class.

```
<div class="tabs"> 
    <div class="ui-widget-header">
        <div class="collapse" id="boxId">Content Box</div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="addPadLeftNoFloat filterArea">
        <p>Content for box</p>
    </div>              
</div>
```

Also change your JavaScript to this:

```
jQuery('.collapse').click(function() {
    jQuery('.filterArea').toggle('slow', function() {

    });
});
```

[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6PCXs/).

Edit: if you only want to collapse `.filterArea` elements with the enclosing `.tab` element, use JavaScript something like this:

```
$('.collapse').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.tabs').find('.filterArea').toggle('slow');
});
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/6PCXs/2/).

Comment: Thank you so much, (i'll accept as answered in 10mins when it lets me)#

Comment: I've just realised though, this will close all the filterAreas on that page when you do it

Comment: @TomBeech: no problem :) I updated my answer for clarity and added a working example.

Comment: @TomBeech: do you only want to collapse `filterArea`s within a given div? e.g. the enclosing `.tabs` element?

Comment: @TomBeech: Updated answer with another possible solution.